Azure App Service Publish Error - Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection
I'm new to app service, i recently created one and tried to publish my asp.net application in it. However getting below error.

There is a fix provided in this post: Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection - Azure App Service
However There is no button for either "Run from package file" or "Deploy as Zip Package" in Publish screen of visual studio 2019
When i checked on "Validate Connection" it gives same error.

Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection. Contact your server administrator if the problem persists. Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED.) WebApplication3 0


If you are behind a corporate firewall or using a VPN, try to disable them temporarily to see if the issue persists.


Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.

This Usually occurs due to network issues and server configuration problems.

If you are behind a corporate firewall or using a VPN, try to disable them temporarily to see if the issue persists.

Mainly, check the app configuration while creating in the portal whether it matches with the webapplication or not.

Here I have opted ASP .net 3.0 for the application. Done with the setup and ready for publish.


Use FTP or the Azure CLI as an alternative.
FTP: Download the publishing profile from the Azure portal and use the FTP credentials to upload the project files.


Successfully deployed:

